# Finding header of CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any easy way to store the values of a CSV file's header? I've been researching but I can't find any info about it.

Comment: Are you just asking how to determine a csv's columns and putting them into a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
df = pd.read_csv(path to file)
df.columns = list(df)  # to put header inside data frame 
print(df)
var = list(df.columns) # to read header from data frame
```